# Mysql query very slow (group by)

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

mysql query very slow but i use `"group by"` function...

i remove group by query and query very fast.

How can I solve this problem?

my query code:

```
$myquery1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM konucuklar 
                         WHERE status='' 
                           and category='football' 
                         GROUP BY matchhour 
                         ORDER BY id asc");
while($myquery1record = mysql_fetch_array($myquery1)){

    $myquery2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM konucuklar 
                             WHERE mactarihi='$bugunt' 
                               and statu='' 
                               and kategori='futbol' 
                               and macsaati='$myquery1record[matchhour]' 
                             ORDER BY id asc");

     $toplams=@mysql_num_rows($myquery2);


     while ($myquery2record=mysql_fetch_array($myquery2)) {     
// code
     } 
}
}
```

Comment: _How long is a piece of string?_ How slow is it? How many rows in the table? Which columns have an index? Can you show the schema for the `konucuklar` table?

Comment: Do you really have the fields category and kategori in the table? And status and statu? Are these fields indexed? Additionally, repeating a query in a loop may very slow, depending on the number of iterations. This can be accelerated by prepared statements, but in your case you query the same table, so there is no need for the query in the loop, as the desired data can be retrieved by the first query.

Comment: @syck How can i solve this problem? i don't know :(

Comment: Unless you tell us what your tables are like, what your explain output is and how much data you have, the answers can only be wild guesses (other than the point that @shadow  hightlighted about your nested loop)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your first query does not comply with SQL standards and will be processed by mysql only if strict sql mode is not enabled.
2. You are issuing the 2nd query in a loop based on the results returned by the 1st query. So, if the 1st query returns 10 rows, then you will execute the 2nd query 10 times. This is very slow. You should rewrite the 2 queries as one, since both queries query the same table and have almost the same where criteria.
3. No idea what the 2nd while loop does, as I can't see where $listele is defined.

Comment: Can't answer that question, you have not shared enough details. You would have to share the table structure with us, provide us with some sample data, and provide the expected outcome for the sample data. I don't think you need group by at all.

Answer (score 0):

The slow down might not be related to the GROUP BY clause. Try adding an index on columns you need to .

Link to understand index : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm

[MySQL Profiling](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/mysql-servers-built-in-profiling-support/) might also help you in your endeavour

Comment: All columns are required :(, i remove group by query and mysql query very fast -> problem "group by" @VERYNET

Comment: GROUP By is an instruction which consumn most ressources in SQL . Did you check the SQL Profiler to understand why your request took this much time ? Removing GROUP BY is not a solution to understand why .

Comment: @mesut The GROUP BY is not needed at all, since you do not use any [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are not optimized and probably could be done better in other way incluiding using only one composed query (JOIN) to fetch all data at once.

Also if your tables have lots of items is good practice to create INDEXES to the fields uses in the common queries for the filter to make the search faster.

Example, your firs select has this complexity (and probably is not well formed)

```
SELECT * FROM konucuklar WHERE status='' 
                           and category='football' 
                         GROUP BY matchhour 
                         ORDER BY id asc
```

But is used only to get the matchhour for the second query. The minimal optimization is to use a query to fetch only the required field.

```
SELECT DISTINCT matchhour FROM konucuklar WHERE status='' and category='football'
```

Comment: There is no need for a join, because both queries address the same table.